# Find general solution of $xx''=(x')^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve ordinary differantial equation that looks like this:

$xx''=(x')^3$

I'm using the substitution $u(x)=x'$ and now I have

$ \frac{uu'}{u^3}=\frac{1}{x}$

After solving it I obtain with:

$u=-\frac{1}{lnx} +c$ and  going back to x' I have: $ x'=-\frac{1}{lnx} +c$

How can I proceed from here? Integrating both sides doesn't look good, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from this line in your post:
$$\frac{uu'}{u^3}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
Integrate:
$$-\frac{1}{u}=\ln{x}+C$$
Since $u=x'$:
$$-\frac{dt}{dx}=\ln{x}+C$$
$$-dt=(\ln{x}+C)dx$$
Integrate:
$$C_2-t=x\ln x -x +Cx$$
You can keep the implicit form.
$$C_2=t+x\ln x +C_1x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x''}{x'^2}=\frac{x'}{x}$$ yields

$$-\frac1{x'}=\log x+c.$$

Then is suffices to integrate

$$(\log x+c)x'=-1.$$

Comment: Integrating that yields $-t = -x(\ln x - 1) +xc + d$. How can we obtain $x(t)$?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев : You can reformulate it to fit the form for the Lambert-W function. Set $x=e^y$, then you can assemble these terms as $e^{y-1+c}(y-1+c)=-e^{-1+c}(t+d)$ or similar, so that $y-1+c=W(-e^{-1+c}(t+d))$...